# Combobox default value is always SQL table value - c#

Tags: c#, winforms, stored-procedures, combobox, default-value

I am retrieving a `datatable` from a `Stored Procedure` and a `Combobox` is showing that data but I want to show -Select Program- as default value of `Combobox` but it is always showing the first record of datatable.

```
InitializeComponent();
        cbxProgram.Items.Insert(0, "-SELECT PROGRAM-");
        cbxProgram.SelectedIndex = 0;
        cbxProgram.DataSource = SomeBL.GetProgramName().Tables[0];
        cbxProgram.DisplayMember = "ProgramName";

        cbxType.DataSource = SomeBL.GetType("").Tables[0].DefaultView;
        cbxType.DisplayMember = "Type";

        cbxNumber.DataSource = SomeBL.GetNumber("", "").Tables[0].DefaultView;
        cbxNumber.DisplayMember = "Number";

        cbxType.Enabled = false;
        cbxType.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: Setting the `DataSource` will remove all current Items in your Combobox.

Comment: Try to insert `-SELECTED ...` after you assign a `DataSource`.

Comment: it gives me an exception `Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.`

Comment: @UmmEHabibaSiddiqui What type of object is your `SomeBL.GetProgramName().Tables[0]` ?

Comment: `getProgramName` is returning a `datatable` with `varchar` values

Comment: @UmmEHabibaSiddiqui searched around and one way will be to copy `SomeBL.GetProgramName().Tables[0]` table content into some collection, add your custom item in it and manually populate `ComboBox`.

Comment: is there a way I can send first value as `-Select Program` from `Stored Procedure` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add your custom Row to your Table before binding.

I didn't test this, but it should look something like this:

```
DataTable dt = SomeBL.GetProgramName().Tables[0];
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr[0] = "-SELECT PROGRAM-";  // Look at the index of your desired column
dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr,0);      // Insert on top position



cbxProgram.DataSource = dt;
cbxProgram.SelectedIndex = 0;
cbxProgram.DisplayMember = "ProgramName";
```

Answer (score 1):

By using Datasource property, you delete the data exist in the first place. You should insert "-SELECT PROGRAM-" line after you fill the combobox from datasource.
Try this:

```
cbxProgram.DataSource = SomeBL.GetProgramName().Tables[0];
cbxProgram.DisplayMember = "ProgramName";
cbxProgram.Items.Insert(0, "-SELECT PROGRAM-");
cbxProgram.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: I got an exception on the first line of your code `InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'.`

Comment: This can't work because after Setting DataSource the Item Collection is protected.

Comment: is there a way I can send first value as `-Select Program-` from `Stored Procedure` ?

Comment: @UmmEHabibaSiddiqui You are right, I didn't noticed you set the line as the selectedindex, which is a little unnecessary since it is a loading page. I edited the code.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't let you add another line after setting datasource, you may consider adding the line to the source datatable. (I don't recommend adding it from SQL database by changing your stored procedure.)

Check this pseudocode:

```
SomeBL.GetProgramName().Tables[0].Rows.Add(new DataRow(0, "-SELECT PROGRAM-"));
cbxProgram.DisplayMember = "ProgramName";
cbxProgram.Items.Insert(0, "-SELECT PROGRAM-");
cbxProgram.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: I got an Compile Time error `Error 1 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments`

Comment: I said "Pseudocode", It's a code for people who smart enough to get the idea.